# nlme::lmList and stargazer?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `stargazer` to format output from the `lmList` function in the `nlme` package. I can get `stargazer` to work if I manually index each list element, but not if I just pass `stargazer` the full list. Any suggestions for how I can get `stargazer` to recognize the `lmList` output?

```
library(nlme)
library(stargazer)
data("iris")
m <- lmList(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width | Species, data = iris)
stargazer(m, type = "text") # "% Error: Unrecognized object type.
stargazer(m[[1]], m[[2]], m[[3]], type = "text")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to package all arguments to stargazer as a list and then get stargazer to accept a list of arguments. The magic function to do this is `do.call`.

`do.call`'s first argument is the function and the second argument is the list of arguments to pass to that function in the first argument.

So something like this should work:

```
do.call(stargazer, c(m, type = "text"))
```

Also FYI the tidyverse version of `do.call` is `invoke` so this is the same.

```
invoke(stargazer, c(m, type = "text"))
```

Invoke will be nicer because you can pass additional arguments (like type above) without putting them in the list.

Comment: Thanks, the invoke command works well. So other people know, it is part of the purrr package.